# String to HexString conversion

Tags: android, string, hex

I've got a String filled with hex values like this:

```
received_Value = fffec780
```

The string isn't declared as a hex string, it is declared as a normal string and filled with this characters. But I must define it as a Hex string to make the conversion to int.

```
int_value_receive = Integer.parseInt(received_Value, 16)
```

Because when doing this i'm getting an error.

Comment: Could you post the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

`fffec780`'s value as an `int` is greater than `MAX_INTEGER`.

Try this

```
Long.parseLong(received_Value, 16);
```

Comment: I'm still getting this error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "fffec780???????????...`